# Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory error

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to follow my teacher from a video and this is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String jpql = "SELECT p FROM ansatt p";
    
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("ansattPersistenceUnit");
    
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    
    System.out.println("Kobler til database...");
    
    try {
        TypedQuery<Ansatt> query = em.createQuery(jpql, Ansatt.class);
        List<Ansatt> ansatte = query.getResultList();
        
        for(Ansatt p : ansatte) {
            System.out.println("ID: " + p.getAnsNr());
        }
        
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
    
    System.out.println("Ferdig!");

}
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named ansattPersistenceUnit
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at StartHere.main(StartHere.java:15)
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What is your persistence.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was a missmatch between the ansattPersistenceUnit in createEntityManagerFactory and in persistence.xml

It needed to be

```
<persistence-unit name="ansattPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar error using Tomcat + JNDI and the JNDI name in web.xml, server.xml, context.xml and persistence.xml must all match.